# Azure ServiceBus Unit Testing

Tags: azure, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, azureservicebus

I have a method that connects to an Azure Service Bus Queue and posts messages. I need to Unit test this method. I have created a Mock Interface on the IqueueClient. I am using Moq framework for my unit test.
I am not able assert the test result.

```
public class WebHookClient : IWebHookClient
{
   private readonly ILogger<WebHookClient> _logger;
   private readonly IQueueClient _queueClient;

public WebHookClient(IQueueClient queueClient, ILogger<WebHookClient> logger)
{
   _logger = logger;
   _queueClient = queueClient;
}

public async Task PostAsync(WebHookRequest webHookRequest)
{
try
   {
     var messageAsText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webHookRequest);

     var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageAsText));

     await _queueClient.SendAsync(message);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
```

}

I need to Unit test the above method. So far I have tried the below

```
    public class WebHookClientTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IQueueClient> _queueClient;
    private readonly IOptions<WebHookOptions> _options;
    private readonly Mock<ILogger<WebHookClient>> _logger;
    private readonly IWebHookClient _sut;


    public WebHookClientTests()
    {
        _queueClient = new Mock<IQueueClient>();
        _logger = new Mock<ILogger<WebHookClient>>();
        _sut = new WebHookClient(_queueClient.Object, _logger.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task PostAsync_Verify_Message_Was_sent()
    {
        //Arrange
        var webHookRequest = new WebHookRequest();

        var messageAsText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(webHookRequest);

        var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageAsText));

        _queueClient.Setup(x => x.SendAsync(It.IsAny<Message>())).Returns(Task.CompletedTask).Verifiable();

        //Act 

         await _sut.PostAsync(webHookRequest);

        //Assert

        _queueClient.Verify();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try with the following:

```
_queueClient.Verify(x => x.SendAsync(It.IsAny<Message>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Comment: It works.

Had  to make a slight change 
_queueClient.Verify(x => x.SendAsync(It.IsAny<Message>()), Times.Exactly(1));